# Custom GSAP "hacked" mousewheel scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, easing, gsap

I made a custom content scroller with jQuery and GSAP in the aim to have a nicer effect than the Chrome basic & stuttered scroll. But I just saw (on Chrome then) that the scroll is laggy and well bugged when I test it with my Wacom tablet (with pen + horizontal scroll, or any trackpad/touch stuff I guess).

Any thoughts about tweaks to render a more *natural* scroll effect, not hacked like now?
Maybe it's something about the `mousewheel DOMMouseScroll` event, or my method is bad, the markup/css need some changes…?

```
$("section").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 || -e.originalEvent.detail; // Chrome || FF

    // Move thumbs
    TweenLite.to($("#photos"), 1.2, {
        scrollLeft: $("#photos").scrollLeft() - parseInt(delta * 35),
        ease: Expo.easeOut,
        overwrite: 5,
        onUpdate: move
    });
});
```

—
http://jsfiddle.net/h66tatp6/

Many thanks for your lights!

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel, use the interface the user is used to.

Comment: Totally agree with it but actually the scroll is very ugly on Chrome… I just want to tween the scroll position of a standard scrollbar, then I tried something but it seems to be a dark solution!

Comment: lots of plugins that have done this...and have been battle tested cross browser

Comment: Yep. But the fact is I already use GSAP & jQuery which are not so light. Another plugin to do a simple thing is enough :/

Comment: the problem is that adjusting scroll triggers scroll events, so if your scroll event scrolls, then things get out of hand quick. a debounce might help, and underscore's let you use a trailing edge, which would be ideal. but, you should still compensate for OS-provided user settings like "scroll one page at a time", or else you'll drive folks nuts... also make sure it works with and without smoothscrolling enabled on firefox. also, some wheels and some mouse drivers use deltas other than 120, so head's up.

Answer (score 1):

Cooked up something. Not really sure if it fits your needs or if it is exactly the type of thing you were looking for, but perhaps it will give you some ideas.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/tah_med/full/ZGGQZm/).

**JavaScript:**

```
/*global TweenMax,Power2,Power4*/
var initIntervalID=null,initInterval=10;
var scrollBar=document.querySelector('.scrollbar');
var scrollBarHandle=document.querySelector('.scrollbar__handle');
var scrollBarBg=document.querySelector('.scrollbar__bg');
var container=document.querySelector('.container');
var images=document.querySelector('.images');
var thumbs=document.querySelectorAll('.thumb');
var numThumbs=thumbs.length;
var resizeID=null,resizeTimeout=400,resizeDuration=.4,resizeEase=Power2.easeOut;
var initDuration=.4,initEase=Power2.easeOut,initStagger=.1;
var duration=.4,ease=Power2.easeOut;
var force3D=true;
var windowWidth=window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight=window.innerHeight;
var thumbWidth=200,thumbHeight=200,thumbGutter=20;
var scrollBarBgHeight=10,scrollBarBgWidth=thumbWidth,scrollBarHandleWidth=20,scrollBarGutter=10;
var imagesPositions=[],iterator=0,percentages=[],scrollBarHandlePositions=[];
function init(){
    initImages();
    initScrollbar();
    initPositions();
    assignListeners();
}
function onMouseWheel(event){
    var e=window.event||event;
    var delta=Math.max(-1,Math.min(1,(e.wheelDelta|| -e.detail)));
    if(delta>0){
        iterator-=1;
        if(iterator<0){
            iterator=0;
            TweenMax.to(images,duration*2,{bezier:{type:'thru',values:[{x:imagesPositions[iterator]+(thumbWidth+thumbGutter)*.1},{x:imagesPositions[iterator]}]},ease:ease});
            TweenMax.killTweensOf(scrollBar);
            TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:1,ease:ease});
            TweenMax.to(scrollBarHandle,duration*2,{
                transformOrigin:'left',
                bezier:{type:'thru',values:[{scaleX:.2},{scaleX:1}]},
                ease:ease,
                onComplete:function(){ TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:0,ease:ease}); }
            });
        }else{
            TweenMax.to(images,duration,{x:imagesPositions[iterator],ease:ease});
            TweenMax.killTweensOf(scrollBar);
            TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:1,ease:ease});
            TweenMax.to(scrollBarHandle,duration,{
                x:scrollBarHandlePositions[iterator],
                ease:ease,
                onComplete:function(){ TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:0,ease:ease}); }
            });
        }
    }else{
        iterator+=1;
        if(iterator>numThumbs-1){
            iterator=numThumbs-1;
            TweenMax.to(images,duration*2,{bezier:{type:'thru',values:[{x:imagesPositions[iterator]-(thumbWidth+thumbGutter)*.1},{x:imagesPositions[iterator]}]},ease:ease});
            TweenMax.killTweensOf(scrollBar);
            TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:1,ease:ease});
            TweenMax.to(scrollBarHandle,duration*2,{
                transformOrigin:'right',
                bezier:{type:'thru',values:[{scaleX:.2},{scaleX:1}]},
                ease:ease,
                onComplete:function(){ TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:0,ease:ease}); }
            });
        }else{
            TweenMax.to(images,duration,{x:imagesPositions[iterator],ease:ease});
            TweenMax.killTweensOf(scrollBar);
            TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:1,ease:ease});
            TweenMax.to(scrollBarHandle,duration,{
                x:scrollBarHandlePositions[iterator],
                ease:ease,
                onComplete:function(){ TweenMax.to(scrollBar,duration,{autoAlpha:0,ease:ease}); }
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function listenToMouseWheel(){
    if(container.addEventListener){
        container.addEventListener('mousewheel',onMouseWheel,false);
        container.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',onMouseWheel,false);
    }else{
        container.attachEvent('onmousewheel',onMouseWheel);
    }
}
function adjustContainerOnResize(){
    windowWidth=window.innerWidth;
    windowHeight=window.innerHeight;
    TweenMax.to(container,resizeDuration,{
        x:windowWidth*.5-thumbWidth*.5,
        y:windowHeight*.5-thumbHeight*.5,
        ease:resizeEase,
        force3D:force3D
    });
}
function onResize(){
    clearTimeout(resizeID);
    resizeID=setTimeout(adjustContainerOnResize,resizeTimeout);
}
function listenToResize(){
    (window.addEventListener)?window.addEventListener('resize',onResize,false):window.attachEvent('onresize',onResize);
}
function assignListeners(){
    listenToResize();
    listenToMouseWheel();
}
function initPositions(){
    for(var i=0; i<numThumbs; i+=1){
        imagesPositions[i]=-i*(thumbWidth+thumbGutter);
        percentages[i]=i*(100/numThumbs);
        if(i===0){
            scrollBarHandlePositions[i]=0;
        }else if(i===numThumbs-1){
            scrollBarHandlePositions[i]=scrollBarBgWidth-scrollBarHandleWidth;
        }else{
            scrollBarHandlePositions[i]=i*(scrollBarBgWidth/(numThumbs-1))-scrollBarHandleWidth*.5;
        }
    }
}
function initScrollbar(){
    TweenMax.set(scrollBar,{
        y:scrollBarGutter,
        width:scrollBarBgWidth,
        height:scrollBarBgHeight,
        force3D:force3D
    });
    TweenMax.set(scrollBarHandle,{y:0,force3D:force3D});
    TweenMax.to(scrollBar,initDuration,{delay:initStagger,opacity:1,ease:initEase});
}
function initImages(){
    for(var i=0; i<numThumbs; i+=1){
        TweenMax.set(thumbs[i],{x:i*(thumbWidth+thumbGutter),force3D:force3D});
    }
    var width=numThumbs*(thumbWidth+thumbGutter)-thumbGutter;
    TweenMax.set(container,{y:windowHeight*.5-thumbHeight*.5,x:windowWidth*.5-thumbWidth*.5,height:thumbHeight+scrollBarGutter+scrollBarBgHeight,width:thumbWidth,force3D:force3D});
    TweenMax.set(images,{height:thumbHeight,width:width,force3D:force3D});
    TweenMax.staggerTo(thumbs,initDuration,{opacity:1,ease:initEase},initStagger);
}
initIntervalID=setInterval(function(){
    if(document.readyState==="complete"){
        clearInterval(initIntervalID);
        init();
    }
},initInterval);
```

Beware of ugly, non-refactored, highly un-tested, un-optimized code. Created only for fun. If I find time, may be I will build upon it later and include other mouse interactions such as `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup` as well as touch interactions such as `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` events. Should be fun. For now, use it as you may like.